# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Welcome#index Getting Started with Rails 4.2.6 OSX 10.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

I get this error when trying to complete the Getting Started with Rails tutorial.
Someone posted a similar question when getting this error in Windows [[ExecJS::RuntimeError running the Getting Started with Rails blog on cygwin (windows7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599718/execjsruntimeerror-running-the-getting-started-with-rails-blog-on-cygwin-wind]) and it seems like it's some kind of path issue.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you running this on windows, or osx?

Comment: Essentially rails requires some server side engine to run javascript, there are a couple of solutions. Most people I know have node.js installed, which should solve your error if rails also knows where to find it. If you don't have it installed you could try that, and go on by asking 'why rails can't find nodejs'.

Comment: I am running this on osx. I will try installing node and update on the status.

Comment: Yep, it was that simple! I had node installed but rails wasn't seeing it. Did a `brew uninstall node` followed by a `brew install node` and it worked. Go figure!

Comment: Glad it works now :) Enjoy learning rails!